# VB-write selected item from combo box into a text file

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a list of items in my combo box. I need to save the selected item only into a text file. My idea is something like this.

```
    Dim stream As New System.IO.FileStream("C:\CONFIG\PA.txt", IO.FileMode.Append, IO.FileAccess.Write)
    Dim write As New System.IO.StreamWriter(stream)
    Dim PA As String = (ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    write.WriteLine(PA)
```

But I couldn't figure out the correct way to do it. Can anyone help?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to check for a selected item before proceeding.

Then write it like this:

```
  If Not ComboBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
     File.WriteAllText("c:\config\pa.txt", ComboBox1.Text)
  End If
```